# How do I sum [add] multiple columns from joined tables

Tags: mysql

I need to write a query that joins several tables and totals several columns in different tables & can't seem to figure out how to do it:

here are the tables:

[image: Contracts table]

[image: Contract Budgets]

[image: program names]

The result I am trying to get is a result with the contract budgets for a particular budget name added: i.e. [this does not work but gives an idea]

```
select c.contract_budget_f1, c.contract_budget_f2, cb.budget_type_id, c.id, sum(cb.budget_f1) as bf1, sum(cb.budget_f2) as bf2
from `flow_contract` c 
left join `flow_contract_budget` cb on cb.contract_id = c.id
where c.program_id = '69'
group by cb.budget_type_id
```

with the whole result set looking like:

```
[budget_type_id]    
[contract_budget_f1]
[contract_budget_f2]
[bf1]
[bf2]
```

where it will return 3 rows with the budgets for each budget type added
How can I do this, is it even possible?

Here are links to the tables - sorry, didn't realize you couldn't click on them...

http://media.bigblockstudios.ca/stack/program-name.gif

http://media.bigblockstudios.ca/stack/contract-budget.gif

http://media.bigblockstudios.ca/stack/contracts.gif

**UPDATE**

I got it working like this:

```
    select c.id, c.program_id, c.contract_budget_f1, c.contract_budget_f2, cb.budget_f1, cb.budget_f2, cb.budget_type_id, c.id, 
sum(cb.budget_f1) as bf1, sum(cb.budget_f2) as bf2 
from `flow_contract` c 
left join `flow_contract_budget` cb on cb.contract_id = c.id 
where c.program_id = '".$formfields['program_id']."' 
group by cb.budget_type_id 
order by cb.budget_type_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is:

```
group by cb.budget_type_id, cb.contract_id
```

Or the other way around. Could you make an sql fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: subquery

Try this:
Start with a subquery.

1. Write a query that produces the column values that you want to sum.  This is now the subquery.
2. Write an outter query that sums the desired columns in the inner query.

After you get it working, review it to see if you can optimize out the subquery and just have one query.